# unable to print char* pointing to 0

Tags: c++

here the comment2 is printed perfectly. where as comment is not printed and the
program ends as soon as it that statement is executed.
Can anybody provide solution?

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   const char * comment = 0;
   const char * comment2 = "hello this is not empty";
   std::cout << std::endl;
   std::cout << comment2 << std::endl;
   std::cout << "printing 0 const char *" << std::endl;
   std::cout << comment << std::endl;
   std::cout << "SUCCESSFUL" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It's the difference between printing nothing (string ending with a zero-byte) and printing something pointed to by a zeroed pointer ... (actually the program crashed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::cout << comment << std::endl;`

When `comment` is 0, we call this a segmentation fault, and is a catastrophic crash. What do you intend to happen here?

do you want `const char * comment = "0";` to print 0
You can do `const char * comment  = "";`  to represent empty string.

---

`const char *` is a pointer. When 0 is assigned to it, it becomes a null pointer because it is now a pointer to null. When you perform cout, the library tries to access the memory at that location, a process called dereferencing a pointer. This causes a crash as explained below.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29#C_pointers)

> Dereferencing a null pointer in C produces undefined behavior,[5] which could be catastrophic. However, most implementations[citation needed] simply halt execution of the program in question, usually with a segmentation fault.

Comment: const char * comment = "" works fine.
but if we assign zero to const char * it is stopping at that point.
it is not executing any statement after that.
i wanted to know why is that behavior?

Answer (score 4):

Dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behaviour, and this makes `comment` a null pointer:

```
const char * comment = 0;
```

If you want an empty string change to:

```
const char* comment = "";
```

Or use `std::string`:

```
std::string comment;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assigning a pointer to 0 means assigning it to NULL. If you want the character 0, change it to string, "0" or for empty string, "".

```
const char * comment = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const char * comment = 0;
```

is equal to

```
const char * comment = NULL;
```

if you want to print character `0`, try below code:

```
const char * comment = "0";
```

As you tag c++,  better use

`std::string comment("0");`